# Angular beginner: How to use factories + $http + json file?

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that doesn't work:

```
toDoListApp.factory("blahFactory", function($http) {
    return {
        getChores : function() {
            return $http({
                url: '/chore.json',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And a `chore.json` file that has data:

```
{"name":"laundry","hours":"3"},{"name":"dishes","hours":"0.5"},{"name":"blah","hours":"1.5"}
```

And my controller uses this factory but breaks on that line:

```
toDoListApp.controller("ChoresController", function($scope, choresFactory, blahFactory) {

    blahFactory.getChores().success(function(data) {
        $scope.blah = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    ....
```

The trace in my firebug console is not very descriptive: `Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data` + a bunch of angular junk that does not make sense. Can anyone help explain? Is my JSON invalid?

=== **UPDATE** ===

Ok so I'm trying to put the array brackets into the json file and modified the $http.get function in my factory to use `cache: false` but it still doesn't update my json because it's cached...

=== **ANSWER** ===

So I deleted chrome's cache and added array brackets and everything worked!

Comment: Your json data dosen't seem properly formatted. Should be inside an Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't correct. You just have three objects next to each other, instead, put those in an array like this.

```
[
  {"name":"laundry","hours":"3"},
  {"name":"dishes","hours":"0.5"},
  {"name":"blah","hours":"1.5"}
]
```

everything else looks great.

Comment: Oh ok. but another issue I think is that the browser keeps caching my json, so when I try to play around with it it never updates on the browser and I don't know if I'm fixing it or not. How do I stop the cache?

Comment: read the documentation. The $http service has a cache option. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Correct, I would advise you grant this answer to @Tyler. Your question has been answered.